# How to create a react-admin app from the tuto?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, react-admin

Im using ubunto and i' m trying to create a react-admin  app.

this is the command i use "yarn create react-admin test-admin"  then  i Choose JSON Server as the data provider, then None as the auth provider.  i didn't add
any resource and i just press Enter. Finally, i choose  yarn and press Enter.

I get this error : at makeError$1 (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:1962:24)

ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/node_modules/create-react-admin/templates/common'

```
at ENOENT (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:1977:10)

at ZipFS.resolveFilename (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:3559:15)

at ZipFS.lstatSync (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:3428:28)

at /tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:4733:20

at /tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:5155:60

at ZipOpenFS.getZipSync (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:5284:14)

at ZipOpenFS.makeCallSync (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:5155:17)

at ZipOpenFS.lstatSync (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:4730:17)

at VirtualFS.lstatSync (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:4182:24)
```

i was expect to create a new admin app based on an existing REST API following the tutorial in the documentation page : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html

Comment: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/node_modules/create-react-admin/templates/common' 
    at makeError$1 (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:1962:24)
    at ENOENT (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:1977:10)
    at ZipFS.resolveFilename (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:3559:15)
    at ZipFS.lstatSync (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:3428:28)
    at /tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:4733:20
    at /tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:5155:60
    at ZipOpenFS.getZipSync (/tmp/xfs-9f3e1446/dlx-17795/.pnp.cjs:5284:14)

Comment: Try `yarn add react-admin` first then follow the steps you mentioned

Comment: still the same Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/node_modules/create-react-admin/templates/common'
    at makeError$1 (/tmp/xfs-fbb0334e/dlx-27063/.pnp.cjs:1962:24)
    at ENOENT (/tmp/xfs-fbb0334e/dlx-27063/.pnp.cjs:1977:10)
    at ZipFS.resolveFilename (/tmp/xfs-fbb0334e/dlx-27063/.pnp.cjs:3559:15)
    at ZipFS.lstatSync (/tmp/xfs-fbb0334e/dlx-27063/.pnp.cjs:3428:28)

Comment: the [common](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/create-react-admin/templates/common) directory is missing, try this [solution](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2240#issuecomment-300762981)

Comment: Note that the `--check-files` flag only works for yarn 1.x

Comment: I'm creatiing a new app from scratch not using an old one . the process of creating stop and give me that error and i found the folder emty

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by running the following two commands:
`yarn global remove create-react-admin` and then `yarn global add create-react-admin`.

Hope this helps.